# Securing API keys in firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Am using Firebase to develop a backend for an iOS app. The firebase-iOS setup makes you download GoogleService-Info.plist to your project which contains API_KEY string among other keys used to identify the firebase project. In production, on a jailbroken device, the plist contents can be read easily I assume? How do I secure this information from prying eyes?

Comment: The API keys in the GoogleServices-info.plist are not secret information. They are just identifiers needed for your app to be able to find its Firebase back-end. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/what-is-the-firebase-apikey-for

Comment: Thanks, issue solved. Read through the security rules